# Chartjs bar chart position

Tags: user-interface, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a bar chart that looks like this design:

[image]

My current chart looks like this (ignore the 2 missing bar elements):

[image]

The two questions I have are:

1. How can I shift the bars so that they're up against the y-axis like in the design?
2. How can I remove the excess x-axis after the last bar element?

Look at this picture I did on paint to get a better idea of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `offset` to false in the `options`:

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      offset: false,
    },
  },
};
```

when `offset` is equal to true, there will be some space around the chart. If it is false, the space will be removed.

[official document](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html)